# How to select all input with given name if name contains [ and ]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

How to select all input with given name if name contains [ and ]?

```
$('input[name=field_name[array_key]]').removeClass('selected');
```

Console:

> Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=field_name[array_key]]

Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `name` value in quotes:

```
$('input[name="field_name[array_key]"]').removeClass('selected');
```

As stated by the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

> Quotes are mandatory

Here's a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/9r47C/1/) of the above code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name=field_name\\[array_key\\]]').removeClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

escape the special characters like `[]` characters

```
$('input[name=field_name\\[array_key\\]]').removeClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape with "`\\`"

From Jquery docs:

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must
>   escape the character with two backslashes: \. For example, if you
>   have an element with id="foo.bar", you can use the selector
>   $("#foo\.bar")